# DXChart WPF export PDF

Tags: wpf, charts, devexpress

Can anyone tell me if I can export DXCharts to .xls, .pdf or any kind of vector format?
I am using DXChart from the 2011 v2 release for WPF.

I didn't find anything about this on the web. My fear is that I can't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use DXCharts along with XtreReports and a report can be exported to PDF.

*Note:* I do not know if the resulting chart is then a vector or a bitmap

Answer (score 0):

I also added this question on the DevExpress site: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q394532.aspx

Finally i got to this conclusions:

The DevExpress charts can be exported to JPG by converting the visual content of the chart to a bitmap and saving it as an image file. They can also be exported to PDF, XLS directly using several techniques which are somewhat poorly documented, but with actual results. The list of techniques is shown below:
-   Integrating the DXChart in a DXGrid and exporting the grid (to PDF, HTML, MHT, RTF, XLS, XLSX, CVS, TXT, XPS, BMP, EMF, WMF GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF) as shown here http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Printing/info.xml. However, the chart will be exported as an image and integrated into the appropriate format file. 
-   No vector format is available, per se, however the image format files allow for a great dpi resolution, which enables a good resize and zooming behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void exportChartToPDF()
{
    PrintSizeMode sizeMode = PrintSizeMode.Stretch;
    chart3D.ExportToPdf("Output.pdf", sizeMode);
    Process.Start("Output.pdf");
}
```